# How to call a COM method that takes a pointer to a BSTR from c#

Tags: c#, interop, marshalling

I'm trying to call the following "foo" COM method from c#:

```
interface IFoo : public IUnknown
{
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall foo( BSTR * log ) = 0;
}
```

Here is how I declare it in c#:

```
[ComImport, Guid( "98D93A58-2889-43a5-A182-47DEE781D41E" ),
 InterfaceType( ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown )]
public interface IFoo
{
    void foo( out string log );
}
```

Here is how I call it in c#:
(x is an instance of the COM class that implements IFoo)

```
string log;
x.foo( out log );
```

When I run this code, I get the following exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException was unhandled
  Message=Marshaler restriction: Excessively long string.
```

What am I doing wrong?

By the way, the following works correctly if I call "foo" from c++ as follows:

```
CComBSTR log;
pX->foo( &log );
```

Comment: I don't think you need the out specifier on the C# side.

Comment: Do you have control over `IFoo` ? If you could change BSTR* to LPSTR* you could then use `StringBuilder` instead of `String` - that's what resolved this error for me

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `ref` specifier.  See the examples at [Default Marshaling for Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h.aspx), especially PassStringRef1 and PassStringRef2.

```
The following example shows strings declared in the IStringWorker interface.
Visual C++

public interface IStringWorker {
void PassString1(String s);
void PassString2([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]String s);
void PassString3([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]String s);
void PassString4([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]String s);
void PassStringRef1(ref String s);
void PassStringRef2([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]ref String s);
void PassStringRef3([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]ref String s);
void PassStringRef4([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]ref String s);
);

The following example shows the corresponding interface described in a type library.

[…]
interface IStringWorker : IDispatch {
HRESULT PassString1([in] BSTR s);
HRESULT PassString2([in] BSTR s);
HRESULT PassString3([in] LPStr s);
HRESULT PassString4([in] LPWStr s);
HRESULT PassStringRef1([in, out] BSTR *s);
HRESULT PassStringRef2([in, out] BSTR *s);
HRESULT PassStringRef3([in, out] LPStr *s);
HRESULT PassStringRef4([in, out] LPWStr *s);
);
```

Comment: I tried the PassStringRef2 example. This still results in the same exception: Excessively Long String.